# Check if value is in array always returning true

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, if-statement

i'm checking to see if pages are in array currently when clicking on `hsc.html` and `index.html` i'm still seeing the alert("debug") which is `==` to requested page not !=

```
experimentPages = new Array();
experimentPages[1] = "index.html"
experimentPages[2] = "hsc.html"

$('a').click(function () {

    var reqestedPage = $(this).attr("href");

    if ($.inArray(experimentPages) != reqestedPage) {
        alert("debug")
    }
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation for [`$.inArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)? You're using it wrong.

Comment: What do you have in the href?

Comment: Isn't the proper syntax `$.inArray(requestedPage, experimentPages)`

Comment: On a side  note arrays should start at 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method works as follows

```
$.inArray( value, array_to_check )
```

and returns -1 if not found, otherwise it returns the position of the value in the array.

```
var experimentPages = [
    "index.html",
    "hsc.html"
];

$('a').click(function () {
    var reqestedPage = $(this).attr("href");
    if ($.inArray(reqestedPage, experimentPages) != -1) {
        alert("it exists");
    }else{
        alert("no luck");
    }
});
```

note that the href has to match exactly the values in the array

Comment: if ($.inArray(experimentPages, reqestedPage) != -1) {
           alert("it exists");
       }else{
        $(this).bind('click',windowUnload());
  }

When clicking a href that is in the array the else is still not returning

Comment: Then console.log requestedPage and see what it returns

Comment: console.log(experimentPages); shows the full array 
console.log(reqestedPage); the selected href that matches the value in the array.  console logging  console.log($.inArray(experimentPages, reqestedPage) != -1) in the else brackets shows false, so         $(this).bind('click',windowUnload()); should be hit

Comment: `$(this).bind('click',windowUnload());` doesn't really look valid, you're not referencing the function but calling it ?

Comment: this works the same 

   var myvar = "bsc.html"
    
     if( reqestedPage != myvar ) {
      $(this).bind('click',windowUnload());
     }

i just want to make the code a bit more reusable so you dont have to define multiple vars and if/elseif statments

Comment: windowUnload() is defined further up script

https://github.com/jkirkby91/UiExperiment/blob/master/experiment/js/experiment.js

Comment: That's great, but that event handler doesn't work, try `$(this).on('click', windowUnload);`

Comment: both the syntax of the event handler work it's this that keeps evaluating false   if ($.inArray(experimentPages, reqestedPage) != -1)

Comment: Try `if ($.inArray(experimentPages, $.trim(reqestedPage)) != -1) `

Comment: my console.log shows they match perfectly

console.log(reqestedPage) ahs.html
console.log(experimentPages) ["index.html", "ahs.html"]

Comment: Oboy, that's my bad (emberassed)! It's correct in the explanation in my answer, it's `$.inArray( value, array_to_check )` but in the code I somehow got them wrong, placing the array first, and then the value, and that doesn't work. I had to step through the code to figure it out, hard to notice by just looking at it.

Comment: hmm yes i see, it is working but buggy, for example when clicking on a page not in array the dialogue box comes up i click stay on page then all links including the ones in the array hi the function, but thanks i've noted your help in the documentation